# Dynamically composed email notifications In ClearQuest Web Version 8

Tags: email, vbscript, clearquest

We recently upgraded from ClearQuest Version 7 to Version 8.  Our users interface through ClearQuest Web, rather than clients.  The VBScript that used to dynamically compose our email notifications in rich text (HTML format) to facilitate our engineering change workflow does not work in Version 8 even though all the other legacy hooks we have tested seem fine.

The only online suggestions we have found say they are valid for Version 7 and above, but stepping through the procedures we find things that don't match the Version 8 environment.

If anyone has successfully substituted a custom VBScript for the built-in plain text, fixed content, static addressee Email Rule feature, we would like to hear from them.